# How can I restrict the results from elasticsearch to only include parent-type documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I'm kinda stuck on this issue and struggling to find a solution:

I do have two types of entries in my shared Elasticsearch index, which are joined by a parent:child relationship.

I'd like to only receive documents of the "parent" type, but also include all "parent" documents which do not actually have child documents available.

Is there any way to implement this?

Best wishes,
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query is what you are looking for. I've made use of the [Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query

Let's say you have the below mapping for parent-child i.e. have `question` and its children are `answer`.

### Mapping

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": { 
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "question": "answer" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  "term":{ "my_join_field":"question" }},
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "must_not":[  
                     {  "has_child":{  
                           "type":"answer",
                           "query":{ "match_all":{} }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The above query would display all the parent documents i.e. `question` which doesn't have any children i.e.m`answer`.

Note that if you convert `must_not` into `must` in the above query, it would return you all the parent documents i.e. `question` which has children i.e `answer` ;)

Now if you want only parent documents. i.e. all the parent documents, your query would simply be in the below format:

### Query for all parent documents

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "my_join_field":"question"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

OR it can be as simple as below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "my_join_field": "question"
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I've implemented [Term Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that looks cool, but I'd actually need to get all "questions", both with and without "answer" documents attached .

Comment: hey @lightblader Nevermind, I have updated my answer. Please check the section `Query for all parent documents` and let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hey @Kamal, thanks a lot for your help! It can be so simple sometimes :D